# Behind the scenes of recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, methods, factorial

so I've been recently studying recursion in Java, and while i fundamentally understand it, I don't quite have a grasp on what is happening behind the code. So for example, finding the factorial of 4.

```
public static long factorial(int n) {
    if (n == 0) // Base case
        return 1;
    else 
        return n * factorial(n - 1); // Recursive call
}
```

Can someone explain to me how the code would run. How does n* factorial(n-1) know what factorial(n-1) is equal to as it just recalled itself? I'm quite confused, any explanation would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Best solution: use pen and paper, lots and lots of paper, and step through the code on paper logically as if you were the computer. It also helps to understand the concept of a stack.

Comment: I'll try it cause thinking through it is hurting my head @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: It will do that, but it is a worthwhile exercise.

Comment: To iterate is human, to recurse divine!

Comment: Also look at this [stack exchange q and a](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/25052/in-plain-english-what-is-recursion)

Comment: Also see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355649/behind-the-scenes-of-recursion). ;)

Comment: Nothing linked @HovercraftFullOfEels